# Data.Random.Extras Usage

Tags: list, haskell, random, shuffle

I'm trying to use a ***shuffle*** function from **Data.Random.Extras** package on the list of cards I have created. My code:

```
module Cards where

import Data.Random.Extras

data Suit = Clubs
             | Diamonds
             | Hearts
             | Spades
               deriving (Eq,Enum,Ord,Show,Bounded)

data Value =  Two
            | Three
            | Four
            | Five
            | Six
            | Seven
            | Eight
            | Nine
            | Ten
            | Jack
            | Queen
            | King
            | Ace
                deriving (Eq,Enum,Ord,Show,Bounded)

data Card = Card Value Suit
                deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)

type Deck = [Card]

-- Generate deck of cards
generateDeck :: Deck
generateDeck = [Card val suit | suit <- [Clubs .. Spades], val <- [Two .. Ace]]

-- Print deck of cards
printDeck :: Deck -> IO ()
printDeck deck = putStr (formatDeck deck)
  where
    formatDeck [] = []
    formatDeck (x:xs) = (show x) ++ "\n" ++ formatDeck xs
```

The problem is that when I'm trying to execute ***shuffle $ generateDeck*** on GHCi prompt I'm getting:

```
No instance for (Show (Data.RVar.RVar [Card]))
  arising from use of 'print'
Possible fix:
  Add an instance declaration for (Show (Data.RVar.RVar [Card]))
In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

I spent hours searching and trying to solve/understand this without any success. I would really appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the type of `shuffle` is `[a] -> RVar [a]`. So you don't get back an `[a]` which you could use directly but some mysterious `RVar`. `RVar` is a bit like `IO` in that an `RVar a` is not a value of type `a` but more of a mean of getting a value of type `a`. In order to actually get a value of type `a` you have to use `runRVar :: RandomSource m s => RVar a -> s -> m a`. Looking at the documentation of [`RandomSource`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-fu-0.2.3.0/docs/Data-Random.html#t:RandomSource), there are multiple instances for it. One example would be `MonadRandom m => RandomSource m StdRandom`. So we can use `runRVar` like this (because `IO` is an instance of `MonadRandom`):

```
> import Data.Random (runRVar, StdRandom(..))
> import Data.Random.Extras (shuffle)
> runRVar (shuffle [1..10]) StdRandom :: IO [Int]
[3,10,8,5,6,7,4,2,9,1]
```

Or another instance of `MonadRandom`, that doesn't involve `IO` would be `State StdGen a`:

```
> -- Above imports and
> import Control.Monad.State (State,evalState)
> import System.Random (StdGen,mkStdGen)
> shuffledState = runRVar (shuffle [1..10]) StdRandom :: State StdGen [Int]
> evalState shuffledState $ mkStdGen 0 -- 0 is the seed
[6,8,7,5,10,9,2,3,1,4]
```